# 404 Error with ajax call which works after page refresh (F5)

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript portal-like application (based on JPolite), when modules are loaded with $.ajax jquery call.

But the first request  (when user has just started his browser) is failed with error 404.
Supposing the app is hosted https://localhost:8443/context
Firebug shows a request to /:8443/context/file.html which is incorrect

But after refreshing browser (F5) everything works fine and request became well-formed. The same issue was in another app based on JBoss portal but fixes after migrating to the latest version.

I suppose this may be connected with incorrect caching or so. Unfortunately google did not suggest anything useful so I'd appreciate any answers.

Comment: Perhaps the first ajax call is happening too early? Make sure it's inside a `$(document).ready(function() {` ... `})` or something like that.

Comment: Are you able to post the code snippet that makes the call?

Comment: There is an error in your code. Unfortunately, you've provided no code, so no one will be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I found the solution myself. The problem was that the log was not configured properly and I missed the important record:
`ERROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Already closed`.
After some period of inactivity mysql server closes the current connection and request was failed with AlreadyClosedException. Adding `validationQuery="select 1"` to my context.xml seems fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> After some period of inactivity mysql server closes the current connection

You should be closing connections as soon as you are finished with your database unit-of-work. Not just letting them sit idle until the SQL server closes the connection.

Comment: I think dbcp does that by itself. Architecure is JPA (hibernate) + Spring, so I do not interfere with its connection management (maybe specify number of idle/max connections in pool)